# Is there a way to delete a pending message from a Service Bus Queue in Azure?

Tags: azure, servicebus

I am currently queuing messages to be run at a future date with .scheduledEnqueueTime.  Sometimes the events that the messages are relaying data about change or are deleted, and when this happens I need to delete the message.  I don't see how to find it or interact with it when I search, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: FWIW I'm using a table entry to soft delete them then just not act on them if the soft delete flag is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right Natahan that currently there is no way to cancel (delete) a scheduled message from a Service Bus Queue. We have had other customers run into this scenario and will add this feature in a future milestone. In the meantime I have seen folks use patterns of tracking progress of a certain workitem in [Session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesession.getstate.aspx) and when the scheduled message show up they check to see the Session state and if it is already complete/resolved then just ignore the message (and maybe then null out the session state).

Comment: Just wondering if cancelling a scheduled message has been implemented yet? Or this this workaround still applicable?

Comment: 2016, what about that "future milestone"? :) Can't seem to find information on this.

Answer (score 1):

ASB allows to schedule a message and cancels it on demand, even before becoming visible/available. Find complete blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--canceling-scheduled-messages)

An alternate solution could be to use "`Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging`" and purge messages by en-queue time. Receive the messages, filter by `ScheduledEnqueueTime` and perform purge when the message has been en-queued at the specific time.

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(resourceName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
var client = messagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver(resourceName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
BrokeredMessage message = client.Receive();

if (message.EnqueuedTimeUtc < MessageEnqueuedDateTime)
{
     message.Complete(); 
}
```